# I need to click on 'OK' buttom from ALERT on Internet Explorer with Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, internet-explorer, automated-tests

I need to click on 'OK' Buttom from Alert on Internet Explorer. I tried use `drive.switch_to.alert().accept()`/`.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` on Selenium Webdrive with Python, but it's not working.

How can I focus on this alert and do something to close it.

The alert happens before click on this button:

`<input name="btn_gerar" id="btn_gerar" type="button" onclick="geraRelatorio()" value="Gerar relatório" class="botao" style="">`

Comment: Have tried clicking the okay button itself with a `.click()`

Comment: Yeah I tried, but I don't know how to get ID, CLASS or Xpath from this buttom on Alert. I am using the sintaxe: alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', alert)

Comment: The Alert is on onclick function:

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first move the control from the web page to the alert popup and then try to accept it. That way it is working fine on my side.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>demo</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input name="btn_gerar" id="btn_gerar" type="button" onclick="geraRelatorio()" value="Gerar relatório" class="botao" style="">
      <script>
         function geraRelatorio() {
          alert("Hi!, I am a Simple Alert. Please Click on the 'OK' Button.");
         }
         geraRelatorio();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='Path_to_web_driver...\\IEDriverServer.exe')
driver.get('https://Your_website_URL_here...')
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
alert_obj = driver.switch_to.alert
alert_obj.accept()
#driver.quit()
```

Output:

[image]

Make sure that code to close the alert() get execute after alert() is displayed on the screen. Sometimes code gets executed first and after that alert() gets display so the user thinks that his code is not working.